# Copy PowerPoint file with Python pptx

Tags: python, python-pptx

I'm trying to make a Python code to copy a PowerPoint file. I have the file `test.pptx` which contains pictures (can be totally ignored) and text, with different slides (title, tittle and content, etc). I need to copy the text from this file, and create a new `.pptx` file containing the text in the same format.

I already have a code to extract the text from the file, but I have no clue in what to do next. Any ideas? Thank you.

This is the code to read the text from the file

```py
import collections.abc
from pptx import Presentation

prs = Presentation('test.pptx')

text_runs = []

for slide in prs.slides:
    for shape in slide.shapes:
        if not shape.has_text_frame:
            continue
        for paragraph in shape.text_frame.paragraphs:
            for run in paragraph.runs:
                text_runs.append(run.text)
```